# Flutter Web: How Do You Compress a Video?

Tags: flutter, video-compression

There are packages like [**"video_compress"**](https://pub.dev/packages/video_compress) available for Flutter that can compress videos, remove audio, and manipulate thumbnails, they are primarily focused on mobile platforms such as Android and iOS.
I searched a lot but found no package supporting **Flutter web**.

I need such a package to decrease the video quality and size captured by the camera on Flutter Web (PWA).